# Seed DB in Laravel 6+ with fixed datasets

Tags: laravel, factory, faker

I want to seed my DB with some random but also fixed data sets. 
I have several columns whose data can be random but for one column (`name`) i need a hardcoded array of values which cannot be random, but have to be generated in order.

```
$factory->define(City::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->randomElements(['Tokyo', 'Paris', 'London', 'Milan'], $count = 1, $allowDuplicates = false),
        'code' => $faker->isbn,
        'description' => $faker->paragraph
    ];
});
```

Which should create 4 new rows (without duplicates) in the `City` table where each name is from that array above, but when i run my code in tinker with:

```
$cities = factory(App\City::class)->make();
$cities->save();
```

I get error `TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate/Database/Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `unique()` method on the faker instance:

```php
$factory->define(City::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->unique()->randomElement(['Tokyo', 'Paris', 'London', 'Milan']),
        'code' => $faker->isbn,
        'description' => $faker->paragraph
    ];
});
```

Keep in mind that if you generate more cities than the number of elements in the array you will get an Exception as faker can not find a value which is unique if all the values has already been extracted once.

Anyways, if you need to create items from a fixed collection the solution provided by @ChinLeung would be better and more semantical.

Answer (score 1):

You should allow your factory to generate a random city name, and use your seeder to make sure you have the required dataset.

Update your model factory to this:

```php
$factory->define(City::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->city,
        'code' => $faker->isbn,
        'description' => $faker->paragraph
    ];
});
```

Then in your seeder:

```php
class CitiesTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        collect(['Tokyo', 'Paris', 'London', 'Milan'])->each(function ($name) {
            factory(App\City::class)->create([
                'name' => $name,
            ]);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, i tried it but sadly it doesn't work as Faker generates "names" and not the cities from the array.

Comment: @lordZ3d Maybe you should add the `name` attribute in the fillable array of the City model for this solution to work

Answer (score 1):

For this particular error, try

```
$factory->define(City::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->unique()->randomElement($array = array ('Tokyo','London', 'Paris', 'Milan')),
        'code' => $faker->isbn,
        'description' => $faker->paragraph
    ];
});
```

Then modify your seeder to

```
public function run()
    {
        //
        factory(App\City::class, 4)->create();
    }
```